# How to determine which Linux TLS certificate does allow me to access the given host?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, encryption, proxy

We have two Ubuntu Linux machines behind the corporate MITM proxy which re-encrypts the HTTPS traffic. In order to pass this proxy, we need to add custom TLS certificates to the `/etc/ssl/cert/ca-certificates.crt` file of Ubuntu.

Now, one of our machines was set up correctly, so it could access the host A. Another machine can't do it, probably because the right certificate is missing. We want to know which certificate(s) are "right" and add them to another machine.

The trace of successful session looks like this (some names and IPs are changed):

```
$ curl  -L https://A.com -vvvv
*   Trying 10.123.89.26...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <PROXY> port 3128 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to A.com:443
> CONNECT A.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: A.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs                                                                                                                                                    * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):                                                                                                                            * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CN; DC=appName gitlab; DC=caName sha256; ST=pkiNo 255088; O=EVILCORP; OU=IT; CN=A.com; emailAddress=admin@admin.com
*  start date: Jan 10 09:02:59 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  9 09:02:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "A.com" matched cert's "A.com"
*  issuer: CN=HWIT Enterprise CA 1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

Now, what else information should we collect to be able to say, that, for example, it is the certificate X which allows us to run this session?

By X I mean the certificate as they shown in ca-certificate.crt:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIH0zCCBbugAwIBAgIIXsO3pkN/pOAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwQjESMBAGA1UE
AwwJQUNDVlJBSVoxMRAwDgYDVQQLDAdQS0lBQ0NWMQ0wCwYDVQQKDARBQ0NWMQsw
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't do the same thing for the second host that you did for the first host. See [https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk actually it is exactly our goal to make the second host work the same way our first host works. Of cause if we have control over MITM configuration it would be trivial. Unfortunately, we don't have such information and instead have to work with a black-box-style gateway.

Comment: Also let me clarify that we are the users of both hosts, not administrators. This question is about configuration reverse-engineering and in my opinion may help people better understand how does TLS work internally.

Comment: I had assumed you were interacting with [this](https://mitmproxy.org/) software product, but now I'm not so sure. In any case the answer below should tell how find the CA certificate you need from host A so that you can add it to the file on host B.

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest way**: there is surely a well established way to find and download the CA certificate for the MITM proxy, and that's surely documented somewhere. You shouldn't need to hunt for the correct CA out of the system pool of another machine.

That said, if you really must know how to find the correct CA certificate using only a connection to a random website, keep reading.

---

This can be done in two steps:

1. find the distinguished name of the issuer of the top-most certificate in the chain returned by the server
2. find the CA certificate whose subject distinguished name matches the one just found

---

**Finding the issuer's distinguished name**:

To find the issuer's name, issue a request to pretty much any host. The presented server certificate will be the one from your MITM proxy rather than the real one, but the process is exactly the same.

Let's take an example with `www.google.com`: note that I am intentionally telling `openssl` **not** to use the system CA pool, effectively not trusting anything. When you run it, you do not need the `-no-CApath` argument.

```
$ openssl s_client -no-CApath  -connect www.google.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
   i:OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
---
etc.....
```

The server returned two certificates: the server certificate with `CN = www.google.com` and its issuer (the intermediate CA) belonging to `Google Trust Services`. The intermediate CA was issued by `GlobalSign Root CA - R2`, that's the certificate we need to find.

---

**Finding the matching CA certificate**:
I now need to find the CA certificate that has the matching distinguished name: `OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign`.

To decode a certificate in the system pool, I can use `openssl` again. Let's check just one certificate (if the filename does not help you, you may have to check a lot more than one. A small script should do the trick):

```
$ openssl x509 -text -in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            04:00:00:00:00:01:0f:86:26:e6:0d
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 15 08:00:00 2006 GMT
            Not After : Dec 15 08:00:00 2021 GMT
        Subject: OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
etc...
```

This certificate has Subject distinguished name:

`OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign`

This matches exactly the distinguished name of the issuer. It is **probably** the right certificate (there could be multiple certificates with the same name, usually when certificates get renewed).

---

**Notes**: in your example, a single certificate is returned (instead of the server certificate and some number of intermediate CAs). The same applies: you will need to find the CA certificate with Subject Name: `CN=HWIT Enterprise CA 1` (assuming curl printed the entire name).

As mentioned before, there could be more than one CA with a matching Distinguished Name. The easiest is to add them all to the CA certificates directory. In some cases (not always as this is not required), certificates also have a `Authority Key Identifier` which can be matched against a possible CA's `Subject Key Identifier`.

Comment: It seems like you're solving a different problem here, or perhaps I'm confused. OP appears to be using an open-source package called [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). The CA certificate he needs to install is the mitmproxy snake-oil CA for his mitmproxy instance.

Comment: I think it's correct: he has a cert from their private CA responding to every request and needs to find the private CA certificate from one machine to copy it onto the other machine so it can be properly MITMed. Any request he issues will be MITM and respond with the MITM's certificate. He can extract the issuer DN from that and find the CA file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, no, your answer is generally correct but I think he's doesn't understand how to find the CA file for *mitmproxy*, which is squirreled away in a certain directory on the proxy.

Comment: You do have a point, there are much faster and easier ways to just grab the CA from wherever is standard for the tool in question. I've prefixed my answer with the "normal solution". Leaving the rest in case anyone really wants to know.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: Using mitmproxy as a "corporate MITM proxy" would be a very suboptimal solution and the curl output posted by OP indeed indicates that this is not the case. I'm quite confident that OP has just mistaken the tag for the generic term, I have removed it.

Comment: @MaximilianHils: What is it about the curl output that leads you to believe its not mitmproxy? There nothing about that I can see that would lead me to doubt it.

Comment: The certificate chain looks unlike anything mitmproxy would generate and we also usually don't run on 3128 (while squid and others would). No proof beyond doubt, but pretty sure this not mitmproxy (which is also not suitable peformance-wise).